# multiply two properties inside an object

Tags: javascript, oop

There are two properties for my bike method.front gear and rear gear.i want another property which will be a new property called gear ratio property which can be obtained by multiplying front and rear gear numbers.the code i have written giving continuous error.how it can be fixed.

```
function write() {
    var bicycle = {
        price: 20000,
        model: "raleigh",
        front_gear: 3,
        rear_gear: 7,
        gear_ratio: function () {
            ratio: this.front_gear * this.rear_gear,
        }
    }
    document.write("this is a " + bicycle.gear_ratio.ratio + " speed bike");
}
window.onload = write;
```

Comment: what error ? can you please show error?

Comment: it's saying syntax error at line 14

Comment: And which line is line 14?

Comment: the curly bracket after (ratio: this.front_gear * this.rear_gear,)..my original post had few more html lines before being edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    gear_ratio: function () {
        return this.front_gear * this.rear_gear
    }
    document.write("this is a " + bicycle.gear_ratio() + " speed bike");
```

Is about the best I can recommend you do. If you still want an object:

```
    gear_ratio: function () {
        return {
             ratio: this.front_gear * this.rear_gear
        }
    }
    document.write("this is a " + bicycle.gear_ratio().ratio + " speed bike");
```

It is possible to write something like:

```
function bike(settings){
     // Make settings an object so we can use it always
     if (typeof settings != 'object')
          settings = {}

     // if settings has a price use that, otherwise use 0
     this.price = settings.price || 500;

     this.model = settings.model || "custom";

     this.front_gear = settings.front_gear || 2;

     this.rear_gear = settings.rear_gear || 2;

     this.__defineGetter__("gear_ratio", function(){
        return this.front_gear * this.rear_gear;
     });

}

function write() {
    var bike1 = new bike({
        price: 20000,
        model: "raleigh",
        front_gear: 3,
        rear_gear: 7,
    });
    var bike2 = new bike({
        front_gear: 3,
    });
    document.write("<br /> bike 1 is a " + bike1.gear_ratio + " speed bike by " + bike1.model + " costing " + bike1.price);
    document.write("<br /> bike 2 is a " + bike2.gear_ratio + " speed bike by " + bike2.model + " costing " + bike1.price);
}
```

Where the function call is implied, however this will require your bike to be an actual instantiated class, and won't work in every browser and is harder to debug. Let me know if you want a better explanation.

Comment: it worked fine.can you explain what difference the bicycle.gear_ratio().ratio  makes which is used instead of bicycle.gear_ratio.ratio??

Comment: @user3138436 It's a function call, the only way to get the browser to know that you want the result of the function, and not the function itself(in javascript functions are just special kinds of objects, they have properties and stuff themselves, as such until you put the brackets after it javascript doesn't know you intend to evaluate the contents).

Comment: @user3138436 In my last example(that's really just an idea, I've not written full code for it, but will if you want) the function call is implied, by telling an object definition it needs to register a getter function, called instead of accessing a real property it instead calls the function when the property is accessed.

Comment: honestly i didn't understand the final example as i have just started  to learn oop..it was a whole new concept for me..

Comment: I've made a sample of the second version, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26NCr/

Answer (score -6):

change this

```
window.onload = write;
```

to this

```
window.onload = write();
```

you're calling the function in an inappropriate way

Comment: Don't do that - this will call `write()` immediately, not `onload`.